# Can the Sequel Gem connect to MySQL over SSL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

Does anyone have any information on how to connect from the sequel gem to a remote mysql database over ssl?  I can connect without ssl but trying to connect as a user who requires ssl just fails with the error message:

```
Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Mysql::Error Access denied for
user 'ssl_user'@'<IP_ADDRESS>' (using password: YES)
```

I can connect fine using the mysql client so I'm guessing that maybe sequel can't handle ssl - though I would have thought that this was the job of the mysql client library.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the patch at http://pastie.org/pastes/1232925/text and specifying either the :sslca or :sslkey options.  If I works, let me know and I'll try to make sure it makes it into the next version of Sequel.